# Как правильно реализовать структуру приложения PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer, qpainter

Нужен совет. Собираюсь написать приложение. Если коротко в нем должна быть возможность чертить прямоугольники, круги, точки... 
Для этой задачи подходит `QPainter`.

Приложение будет большим, поэтому я решил использовать *Qt Designer*, ведь в нем гораздо легче расставлять виджеты.

И вот я не могу понять как в *Qt Designer* добавить в окно `QPainter`? 
Его нет среди предлагаемых виджетов.

Как реализовать задумку? Не хочется добавлять `QPainter` в коде, потому что было бы удобно видеть весь вид приложения сразу в *Qt Designer*.

Comment: **Никак.** QPainter не виджет. Его даже можно использовать и вне виджетов, например чтобы нарисовать на QImage/QPixmap

Comment: Используйте https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html

Answer (score 3):

Класс, который предоставляет `Qt Designer`, **не является виджетом**,
поэтому я рекомендую вам **не изменять его** и не реализовывать там логику,
так как у вас будет несколько проблем, лучше всего создать класс,
который наследует соответствующий виджет в соответствии с шаблоном
и использовать класс `Qt Designer`, чтобы заполнить его.
Данный класс, производный от Python **`object`** type.

`QPainter` предоставляет высокооптимизированные функции для выполнения большинства
программ графического интерфейса для рисования.
**`QPainter` может работать с любым объектом, который наследует класс `QPaintDevice`**.

Класс `QPaintDevice` - это базовый класс объектов, которые можно рисовать с помощью `QPainter`.

Рассмотрим например класс `QWidget` - это базовый класс всех объектов пользовательского интерфейса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Получается мне в любом случае придеться добавлять виджет в окно через код?

Comment: @rew о каком виджете вы говорите? Окно это виджет без родителя.

Comment: Когда я в дизайнере делаю макет приложения с кнопочками и всем подобным, хотелось бы видеть виджет на котором будет происходить отрисовка чертежей. Но если создавать в коде свой виджет с использованием ```QPainter``` то в ```QtDesigner``` его не добавишь.

Comment: @rew я рекомендую вам задать новый вопрос, в котором показать ваш пример и лучше рассказать что вы хотите сделать. Ответ на ваш текущий вопрос - никак.

Comment: Видимо и правда такое нельзя реализовать( В любом случае спасибо

Comment: @rew пожалуйста. Все можно реализовать, только это надо делать правильно.

Comment: @rew  вам надо задать новый вопрос, в котором показать ваш пример и лучше рассказать что вы хотите сделать и я думаю, что вы получите ответ как это надо сделать правильно.

Comment: Примера нет. Я еще только обдумываю как реализовать приложение. Если что-то и уточнять, то то, что мне подойдет вообще любая идея как создать виджет, чтобы он во-первых отображался в ```QtDesigner```, и во-вторых при запуске приложения в виджете можно было рисовать как, к примеру, в ```Paint```.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю использовать [QGraphicsView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) + [QGraphicsScene](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html)

Расширение классов-наследников [QGraphicsItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html) позволит Вам определить поведение нужных примитивов.